# Wildcard with if statement

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower

I am trying to filter out a username for an incoming connection with .xsl file(DataPower appliance).  I have 4 scenarios

user@domain.com - needs to stay the way it is.

user@remove.com - need to remove the domain part.

user@domain.com@remove.com - need to remove only the remove part.

user@remove.com.anything - again need to remove this and everything after.

There are 3 variables here.  The 'user' can be anything.  The domain can be anything.  And the .anything after the remove.com, can be anything.  @remove.com will ALWAYS be the same.  Luckily that is the constant we can use.

Is there a simple if/then statement we can use to do this.  We have tried many variations of If, when, contains, and can't seem to get it working.  I can paste the code we are currently using if that will help.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your XSLT look like so far?

Comment: Have you tried using `substring-before()`?

Comment: We figured it out.  Sorry to jump the gun, we've been at this a few days.(I can't answer my own question yet on this site).  I will update with code once I can.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for your problem can be Regex expressions, try "regexp:match(yourExpressionGoesHere)"
and then you just have to write the specific regex for each case.

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out.  Sorry to jump the gun, we've been at this a few days.

Here's the code:

```
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:variable name="userid" select="substring-after(/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='Authenticate']/*[local-name()='username'],'@')"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="contains($userid,'remove')">     
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:*deleted*">
            <soapenv:Header />  
            <soapenv:Body>
                <urn:authenticate>
                    <userId0>
                           <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='Authenticate']/*[local-name()='username'],'@remove.com')"/>
                    </userId0> 
                    <credential>
                           <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='Authenticate']/*[local-name()='password']"/>       
                    </credential>
                </urn:authenticate>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
       <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:*deleted*">
            <soapenv:Header />  
            <soapenv:Body>
                <urn:authenticate>
                    <userId0>
                           <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='Authenticate']/*[local-name()='username']"/>
                    </userId0> 
                    <credential>
                           <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='Authenticate']/*[local-name()='password']"/>       
                    </credential>
                </urn:authenticate>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:otherwise> 
</xsl:choose> 
    </xsl:template>
```